# Kivy adding text to ScrollView

Tags: python, kivy

I'm coding a dictionary app with kivy. I want to get text from textinput and create a scrollview widget and add results to widget.

```
class dictionary(App):
def build(self):
    self.layout = BoxLayout(orientation="vertical")
    self.first_row = BoxLayout(orientation="horizontal", size_hint_y=1)
    self.examples = BoxLayout(orientation="vertical", size_hint_y=10)

    self.input_ = TextInput(hint_text="Search on ludwig.guru",
                            multiline=False,
                            size_hint_x=2,
                            size_hint_y=1)

    self.search_button = Button(text="Search",
                                on_press=self.search,
                                size_hint_x=1,
                                size_hint_y=1)     

    self.first_row.add_widget(self.input_)
    self.first_row.add_widget(self.search_button)
    self.layout.add_widget(self.first_row)
    self.layout.add_widget(self.examples)

    return self.layout

if name == "__main__":
    dictionary.run()
```

Comment: have you checked the documentation for this on kivy's official site? They've got some pretty good examples, if you still didn't get it or got stuck, then just @ me, ill try to help https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.scrollview.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all to get the text from your `TextInput` use `self.input_.text`, it will give you the text in your text input. Use this in your `self.search` function. Then you can get the results by whatever means you want to. Then to add them to a list you have to use a `ListView` then add `ListItems` inside that list view for each item. You can check kivy [docs](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.scrollview.html) for more details.